# How to create a larger array out of smaller ones? segmentation error

Tags: c, arrays, image, recreate

I'm currently trying to create a 320x240 array for an image but the pixels are sent by line(320 at a time). And so I thought about just running a loop that counts 240 so that at each count I insert my smaller array[320] to that of the bigger array[240][320]

here is the code I've done so far.

```
int main()
{
    int mi,mj,this;
    while(this < 240)
    {
        decodeHex(stringToDecode,hexValues);
        compile(this,hexValues);
        this=this+1;
    }


    for(mi = 0; mi < 240; mi=mi+1)
    {
        printf("\npctureArray [%d][%d]\n",mi,320);
        for(mj=0; mj < 320;mj=mj+1)
        {
            printf("%lx",pictureArray[mi][mj]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void decodeHex(char * encodedString,unsigned long * hexConverted)
{
    int i;
    unsigned long offset = 0x41;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(encodedString);i = i+3)
    {
           *hexConverted = (((unsigned long)encodedString[i]- offset) << 8)  |  (((unsigned long)encodedString[i+1] - offset) << 4) | ((unsigned long)encodedString[i+2] - offset);
           hexConverted = hexConverted + 1;
    }

}

void compile(int i,unsigned long * ptr)
{
    int j;
    for(j= 0;j<320;j=j+1)
    {
           pictureArray[i][j] = (unsigned long)*(ptr+j);
    }

}
```

the decoder part of the code receives a char array[960] and so it is converted to unsigned long array[320]  <--- 960/3 = 320 RGBs

I'm confused as to why my code has segmentation error. Can anyone take a peek and tell me if there's something I'm missing here

Comment: `this` is not initialized, the value is indeterminate, it is not zero initialized. Considering `this` is a keyword in C++ it is probably a poor choice for an identifier.

Comment: The question appears to be about C, not C++. So there should be no problem with `this` as an identifier.

Comment: Thanks guys! anyhow, I've already sorted it out. The problem was that

The problem was on,
char array[960] = " ....960 letters..."

because I think that when you declare a string that way it should be
char array[#ofelems + 1] = ".... #ofelems...."

because of the last line "\0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the intial value of `this`.

```
this = 0;
```

Without initialization, `this` will not be containing `0`.

Comment: I've already sorted it out.pls check my answer. Thank you btw!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! anyhow, I've already sorted it out.

The problem was on,

```
char array[960] = " ....960 letters..."
```

because I think that when you declare a string that way, it should be

```
char array[#ofelems + 1] = ".... #ofelems...."
```

"+1" because of the embedded `"\0"` in the last element

please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!